# Input Device permission error: Beaglebone Black + JavaFx

Tags: debian, java, beaglebone

I am trying to launch a JavaFX app on my beaglebone black running Debian.

When launching as the root user, the application will launch but the touchscreen will bug out a little bit, displaying improperly and messing up the touchscreen touch calibrations.

When I try and launch the app as a normal user, I get the following error messages as the app launches:

```
Udev: Failed to write to /sys/class/input/mice/uevent
      Check that you have permission to access input devices
Udev: Failed to write to /sys/class/input/event0/uevent
      Check that you have permission to access input devices
Udev: Failed to write to /sys/class/input/event1/uevent
      Check that you have permission to access input devices
Udev: Failed to write to /sys/class/input/event2/uevent
      Check that you have permission to access input devices
Udev: Failed to write to /sys/class/input/input0/uevent
      Check that you have permission to access input devices
Udev: Failed to write to /sys/class/input/input1/uevent
      Check that you have permission to access input devices
Udev: Failed to write to /sys/class/input/input2/uevent
      Check that you have permission to access input devices
Udev: Failed to write to /sys/class/input/mouse0/uevent
      Check that you have permission to access input devices
```

The app is then unresponsive to touch input.

How can I give a normal user permission to access the input devices?

Comment: Did you manage to find a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

I just find this post.

I have another solution (maybe more clean).

Modifying udev rules, you can add rights on this files.

```
sudo vi /etc/udev/rules.d/99-com.rules
```

and add following lines:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="input*", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c '\
        chown -R root:input /sys/class/input/*/ && chmod -R 770 /sys/class/input/*/;\
'"
```

Comment: Is there a good reason to change *all* input devices, rather than just setting `MODE` and `USER` values in the udev rules?  BTW, you probably want `ACTION=="add"` in there, too...

Comment: I would like to solve the problem by adding a more specific udev-rule. How would it have to look if I wanted to use the add-action and only allow the necessary devices?

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is related to the mouse issue described [here](http://gluonhq.com/forums/topic/mouse-issue-with-javafx-embedded-port/) you have currently three options:

- start your app as root
- unplug/plug your mouse (or mouse receiver)
  after each app start
- use older jdk 1.8 (<= u60)